# Customizing Cycle Template on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

We are planning to use the Cycle Template for the Application Tile. Moreover, we would like to display specific images when the user has pinned a Wide Application Tile and other images when the user has pinned a Normal Application Tile. 
I know that the Flip Template can specify images for each size of the application tile, but I haven't found the same option for the Cycle Template.

Does somebody know if this is feasible? If so, could you explain how it can be implemented?

An alternative would be to detect when the user changes from Wide-App Tile to Normal-App Tile, however I think this is very unlikely to be possible.

Herb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the Cycle tile template does not support using different images for the wide and normal sizes.

Additionally, it is not possible to tell anything about the primary tile of an app. (i.e. if pinned, what size or where on the start screen it is positioned.) The existence of secondary tiles is all that can be determined about them. There is no way to know the size of a displayed tile.

As Windows 8.1 includes a wider array of tile template options, we can only hope that more tile options come to a future version of Windows Phone.